# Stop a systemd service and clear all persistent data

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that is making use of `DynamicUser` and `StateDirectory` in the unit file, so the service can be restarted freely without losing data. However sometimes I want to completely clean up any persistent data and start it from a blank state, is there any `systemctl` command that can do that?

Comment: Please don't crosspost with SO. https://superuser.com/questions/1341811/stop-a-systemd-service-and-clear-all-persistent-data has a comment pointing to an answer

Comment: Sorry for the duplication, I'm not sure on which site I can get the best answer, and that comment is completely off the mark by the way.